# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 With unetbootin "Invalid Password"

Tags: dual-boot

I'm attempting to install ubuntu 16.04 using unetbootin. I get to the desktop then click install on the desktop. Choosing install alongside windows, it goes through the installation process, I choose a username and password and then after a while leaving it to install, the screen goes black and when it comes back it has logged out. I enter my username and password, but it says "invalid password" everytime.

I have re-attempted installation 4 times and I am 100% certain the username and password I am entering are correct.

Comment: have you tried to do the complete installation again? from the scratch, because it seriously shouldn't happen

Comment: As I said yes, I have tried 4 times.